# Hbase Map reduce and Index

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am crawling different industry data and storing the data into single hbase table. For example I am crawling Electronics and Computer industries and stored in a table called 'industry_tbl'. Now I want to run a map reduce on the sets of data namely for Electronics and computer industries and produce the reducer output with the different sets of data collected but currently hbase is taking the entire data of both the industries and giving me the reduced results which I cant differentiate by Industries.

Any Help or idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Include industry as part of the key you emit in the mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Make industry the most-significant part of your hbase key and use pass that to the SCAN you define for the map-reduce

Comment: Yes I can include but suppose if I have 10 industries I need to explicitly define or run them as ten separate jobs. Any other alternative that would implicitly consider the keys and produce the output in industry sets? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a Column Scan on the Hbase Table.
In order to do that, put all the information for a particular industry under a particular industry column family.

For example, my industry table would probably look like this.

For a given row: cf1-science cf2-technology etc.

This way, your industry data would be closely partitioned in certain regions, bringing down your query time.

Now I would just query by using the Scan api and include a particular column family to scan.

So the scan would return me only the details pertaining to a particular industry.

The row in this case would still remain the same as you would have had it previously.

Hope this explanation helps.